# How to update Resource URL automatically when replicating CKAN to another AWS environment via CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastore, ckan

**Background**

We are implementing CKAN on AWS with the DataStore extension and interact with it via the python CKAN API. AWS is essentially split into two environments:

- PRIV: for internal and QA/Staging purposes, hosted in https://private.company.com
- PUB: for external end-users, hosted in https://private.company.com

PUB is created via CloudFront and uses Read Replica of the PRIV database. It is basically the same as PRIV except that it is read-only.

**Challenge**

Resource URLs in PUB point to the PRIV environment. For example, running `PUB_ckan.resource_show(id='123')` api call in the public environment returns the following:

> { ...
>
> 'datastore_active': False,
>
> 'id': '123',
>
> 'name': 'Resource 1',
>
> 'package_id': 'abc',
>
> 'state': 'active',
>
> 'url': 'https://**private.company.com**/dataset/f688/resource/e3c785/download/file.zip',
>
> 'url_type': 'upload'
>
> ... }

This is the same for files uploaded through the CKAN API or the DataStore extension (in which case they are labeled 'url_type': 'datastore).

**Expectation**

All of the package/resource metadata should be the same between environments, with the exception of Resource URL which must reflect the PUB URL so end-users make api calls against the highly available, secure, environment. i.e.:

> 'url': 'https://public.company.com/dataset/f688/resource/e3c785/download/file.zip'

So far, I have looked into whether the config file contains a setting for using relative URLs and also tried updating the URLs manually via a Python script, both without success. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the same underlying database then the easiest way is probably a small plugin on the public instance which implements the [`IResourceController` interface](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IResourceController) and uses the [`before_show` method](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IResourceController.before_show) of that interface to change the resource URL.

Note, however, the following warning from the documentation of `before_show`:

> Be aware that this method is not only called for UI display, but also in other methods like when a resource is deleted because showing a package is used to get access to the resources in a package.

You should therefore definitely test that your URL modifications do not affect other parts of CKAN.